# How to detect the audio availability in the SUSE Linux system

Tags: linux, audio, suse

I got some audio pieces in **flv** format. Each of them is about **10** seconds long.

My question is how to detect whether the audio pieces has "sound", in other words, sometimes the audio pieces has no sound even the size of it is not 0 byte, so how to find those broken/silent audio files by some linux tool/command?

Maybe ffplay can do this? any available advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to quickly check if the stream is video only, audio only or if it contains both audio and video, try `hexdump -C filename | head`.  The fifth byte contains information about the contents of the file.

0x01 - video only
0x04 - audio only
0x05 - audio + video

You can also try to play the file using VLC media player.  There is a menu option that enables informational messages from the media being played back.